# What formula to use in Excel to return missing text on one cell to another cell

Tags: excel

I am comparing two columns ( A and B) and I wanted to return the missing text/value from column A . MY reference column is B.

```
Column A    Column B   Column C
ana         ana
ray         ray
jack        jack
bryan
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You want whatever is in column A to be in Column B? or C?

Comment: So you'd expect to see Bryan in column C?

Comment: `=B1=A1` will show you whether they are exact match.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formula like this one to compare the columns and return the value of a cell in A if that value is not present in B, but you would have to copy the formula down for all the rows in which column A has data:

=if(iserror(vlookup(a1, B:B, 1, false)), a1, "")

Answer (score 0):

If you want the absent ColB entries to be listed sequentially in ColC, then the following array formula -- entered by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter` should work.  In the formula below, ColA and ColB range references must be the **same size**.  Enter the formula in C1 and fill down as far as needed.

```
C1: =IFERROR(INDEX(ColA,-ROW(ColA)+1+SMALL((COUNTIF(ColA,ColB)=0)*(LEN(ColA)>0)*ROW(ColA),ROWS($1:1)+SUM(--((COUNTIF(ColA,ColB)=0)*(LEN(ColA)>0)=0)))),"")
```

[image]